# Is there a way to use only the object name of a class as a "default" member?

Tags: c++

Think in a similar fashion like:
1. The bare name of an array is equivalent with the pointer to the first element, without the need to specify index 0.
2. `toString()` from Java makes it possible to use the name of an object as a string without calling any object method.

Now is there a way in C++ to use the name of a class object to refer to its first member?
Consider:

```
class Program
{
public:
    int id;
    char *str;
};

void function(int p)
{
//...
}
```

and then:

```
Program prog0;
function(prog0); // instead of function(prog0.id)
```

Any way to "hide" the member reference?
EDIT:
Why was the holyBlackCat's answer deleted? I was inclining to vote it as the best answer -- no offense, Mateusz. But he was the first to suggest conversion operator and the example was complete and simple.

Comment: How does Java's `toString()` work without calling any method?

Comment: The name of an array is *not* equivalent to a pointer.

Comment: @juanchopanza, I think if you pass something where a string is expected, it implicitly calls `.toString()`.

Comment: Something like `toString()` can only work because Java has a root class that is a base of all other classes. If you use a root class for your own C++ objects, you could easily define `toString()` in it as well. (You probably shouldn't, but you could.)

Comment: @chris "implicit" is the key and the term I was looking for!

Comment: You could define a conversion operator, and it wouldn't even need to return the first member, it could return any member you want. But I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for, nor can I say whether it's a good approach for you.

Comment: @chris I was referring to: `arr[0] <=> *arr`

Comment: @mireazma, Okay, I agree with that non-generalized statement.

Comment: @chris not exactly: the `toString` method is only called automatically when concatenating strings, e.g., `"" + someObject` gets interpreted as `"" + someObject.toString()`. There are overloads for functions like `println` that take an `Object` and then call `toString` on it.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta, Ah, okay. I thought Java was more eager to convert things to strings than C#, but I guess not.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta right, I remember I was very confused about this and it took me time to realize what was going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, such behaviour would be a cataclysm. If I understand correctly, Java tries to convert object of type `A` to object of type `B` by searching for first member in `A`, that is of type `B` or is implicitly convertible to `B`.

C++ wasn't designed that way. We like to write code, that is always predictable. You **can** achieve what you want, but for a price.

The best solution in this case would be conversion operator - consider:

```
class Program
{
public:
  int id;
  char *str;

  operator int()
  {
    return this->id;
  }

  //You can have more than one!
  operator const char*()
  {
    return this->str;
  }
};

void function_int(int p)
{
}

void function_str(const char* s)
{
}
```

Now it is possible to do the following:

```
Program prog;
function_int(prog); //Equivalent of function_int(prog.id)
function_str(prog); //Equivalent of function_int(prog.str)
```

The price is, that if you add another `int` and place it before `id` it will not be used in conversion, because we stated in our operator explicitly, that "`int` content" of our class is represented by `id` and this member is considered when it comes to such conversion.

However, even this simple example shows some potential problems - overloading functions with integral and pointer types could result in very unpredictable behavior. When type contains conversion operators to both pointers and integers, it can get even worse.

Assume, that we have following function:

```
void func(unsigned long)
{
}
```

And we call `func` with argument of type `Program`. Which conversion operator would you expect to be called? Compiler knows how to convert `Program` to either `int` or `const char*`, but not `unsigned long`. [This article on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) should help you to understand how implicit conversions work.

---

Also, as Barry pointed out, more meaningless constructs become available. Consider this one:

```
int x = prog + 2
```

What does it mean? It is perfectly valid code, though. That is why conversion operators should be dosed extremely carefully (in pre-C++11 era, there was a general advise, that every class should have at most one such operator).

Quote from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5s5sk305%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> If a conversion is required that causes an ambiguity, an error is generated. Ambiguities arise when more than one user-defined conversion is available or when a user-defined conversion and a built-in conversion exist.

Sometimes, simple solution to this problem is to mark conversion operator with **explicit** keyword, so you would need to change above calls to:

```
function_int((int)prog);
function_str((const char*)prog);
```

It is not as pretty as the previous form, but much safer. It basically means, that compiler is forbidden to perform any implicit conversion using operator marked as **explicit**. Very useful to avoid ambiguous calls, while still providing some flexibility in code - you can still very easily convert objects of one type to another, but you can be sure when and where these conversions are performed.

However, explicit conversion operators are still not supported by some compilers, as this is C++ 11 feature (for example, Visual C++ 11 doesn't support it).

You can read more about **explicit** keyword [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit).

Comment: Now it's also possible to do `int x = prog + 2;` which almost certainly makes zero sense.

Comment: Yes, of course. That's the price of wrong design. Implicit conversions can be harmful. But I see a lot of code written this way every day. That's why I wrote this and explain why **explicit** keyword can help you provide great flexibility without such nonsenses. I will update my answer with your example.

Comment: Thanks. Java doesn't allow anything of the kind, I was just contouring a way of thinking. I was hoping something like the object always would store its members consecutively and the firstly declared member would be always stored at the beginning address of the object and thus taking advantage of this somehow.

Comment: @Barry why would someone code that? Even by mistake. Why wouldn't the one also code `char c = 'M' + 'Y';` plus this would be more likely, as it could be mistaken for concatenation. Yet, it's allowed by the compiler.

Comment: @mireazma Good example, but keep in mind, that all available semantics for built-in types are documented and well-known - it's part of the language after all. With user-defined types, problem is more serious, because in huge apps, it is often desirable to introduce flexible semantics and detecting errors, that originated in an unexpected implicit conversion can be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

> Now is there a way in C++ to use the name of a class object to refer to its first member?

No, C++ doesn't have any reflection, so there's no way to actually determine what the "first member" is.

However, if what you really want is to get an ID for any object, you could just require that object to have that method:

```
template <typename T>
void function(const T& t) {
    int id = t.getID();
    // etc.
}
```

Without knowing more about your use-case, it's hard to know what to propose.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question title as your answer made me see it was incorrect. The function is from OpenGL thus I can't modify it.

Comment: @mireazma Could write your own adapter in-between your objects and OpenGL. Nothing wrong with being explicit either and just passing `prog0.id` - take the path of least surprise!